# Params with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to assign a `params` to a variable in my controller to a variable, for a nested resources.

```
Controller for Transactions:
def create
  @amount = params[:amount] 
  [...]
end


Routes:
resources :accounts do
  resources :transactions
end

View for New Transaction:
<%= form_for([@account, @account.transactions.build]) do |f| %>
  [...]
  <%= f.label :amount %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
  [...]
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

for some reason is returning `nil`. Does the line `@amount = params[:amount]` work only for no nested resources? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: It is no different, please show your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure than params[:amount] actually exists? Inspect the contents of your params variable in the create method to see what data is being passed to your method. Usually in params, the field values such as :amount in your case is encapsulated by the model name and you have to write a reference such as params[:account][:amount] in order to access it.

Comment: `params[:transaction][:amount]`

Answer (score 0):

@amount is an instance variable in the controller(that is passed to the view by the same name).

It is not the same as the amount method in your Account instance (which returns the amount attribute in you model)